# How to run indexer in sphinxsearch Docker container?

Tags: docker, search, sphinx, indexer

I'm using the [macbre/sphinxsearch/](https://hub.docker.com/r/macbre/sphinxsearch/) docker image.
I created the dirs for volumes and I'm running the container with command:

```sh
podman run --name sphinxsearch -p 36307:36307 -v ~/podman/volumes/sphinxsearch/:/opt/sphinx/index:z -v ./sphinx.conf:/opt/sphinx/conf/sphinx.conf:z --rm macbre/sphinxsearch
```

and I get an error, as indexes are not created by the `indexer`:

```sh
WARNING: index 'test1': prealloc: failed to open /opt/sphinx/index/test1.sph: No such file or directory; NOT SERVING
FATAL: no valid indexes to serve
```

How should I run the indexer in this scenario?

Comment: Not sure about this docker image, but if you get a similar issue with Manticore (fork of Sphinx), which has an official docker image - let me know. Here's the instruction how to use Manticore in docker - https://mnt.cr/docker

Comment: Thanks for help. I think I need to try Manitcore Search as it provides popular HTTP JSON protocol.

Comment: I decided to migrate from Sphinx to Manticore. Now I am facing need to completely change my architecture because index update is completely different. This is disappoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before running the searchd daemon you firstly need to build indexes. For this purpose run the first indexer job through the container:

```
podman run -v $VOLPATH/sphinxsearch/index/:/opt/sphinx/index:z \
-v $VOLPATH/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf:/opt/sphinx/conf/sphinx.conf:z \
--rm macbre/sphinxsearch indexer --all --config /opt/sphinx/conf/sphinx.conf
```

Later, when the container is already working, you can refresh indexes with:

`podman exec -it sphinxsearch indexer --rotate --all --config /opt/sphinx/conf/sphinx.conf`

I also documented the whole procedure in the post:
[Running SphinxSearch in Podman container](https://lukaszherok.com/post/view/9/Running%20SphinxSearch%20in%20Podman%20container)

Thanks @Manticore-Search and @macbre for pointing the direction.